# how to create associated record and modify data with has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am a rails newbie and although I have built an app with erb files, ruby and postgres, I find it difficult to find out how to write the syntax for the class methods, especially if you want to do more than just CRUD.

I have two tables: material & material_costs
Material has_one material_cost and material_cost belongs to Material.

Each new entry to Material model should automatically populate the one entry to material_costs. Using three fields from Material, I need to modify the data that will create the new material cost record.

I have spent hours trying to find the correct syntax for a build_with function. Not so easy, even with the rails docs.

code so far:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_entries
  has_one :material_costs, :material_charges, :dependent => :destroy

@material = current_material
@material_cost = @material.build_material_costs(
            :cost_a4 => ((@material.cost_per_sqm +        @material.ink_per_sqm) * 0.0626514876)
            :cost_a3 => ((@material.cost_per_sqm + @material.ink_per_sqm) * 0.124548139)


end

class MaterialCost < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :materials
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateMaterials < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0] 
  def change 
    create_table :materials do |t| 
      t.string :product_name, :guk_name 
      t.integer :roll_width_in, :roll_length_m, :factor, :rounded_sale_price 
      t.float :list_price, :cost_per_sqm, :ink_per_sqm, :supplier_discount, :sell_per_sqm 

      t.timestamps 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Am I on the right track? Anyone know of any user-friendly guides on building the class model methods for basic querying and modification of data?  thanks, godhar

```
class CreateMaterials < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :materials do |t|
  t.string :product_name, :guk_name
  t.integer :roll_width_in, :roll_length_m, :factor, :rounded_sale_price
  t.float :list_price, :cost_per_sqm, :ink_per_sqm, :supplier_discount, :sell_per_sqm
  t.timestamps
   end
  end
end


class CreateMaterialCosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
   create_table :material_costs do |t|
   t.float :cost_a4, :cost_a3, :cost_a2, :cost_a1, :cost_b0, :cost_b1, :cost_b2
   t.float :cost_b3, :cost_b4
   t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

After closing down my machine and the psql server, restarting and getting the server back, re-creating the db, then finally migrating all my migrations I am in error hell. If one has Dropped the tables, what is the convention? Should I edit the migration files so that renaming of columns and all these editing migrations aren't run? i.e. Do I have a chance to start from scratch, or do I have to migrate all my changes as well? Also, are we suppose to add id columns? I thought that through the relationships Rails sets up the ids for us, I am sure I read that somewhere? Where and when do we add id columns?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_entries
  has_one :material_cost, :material_charge, :dependent => :destroy

  after_create do
    self.create_material_cost(
      cost_a4: (self.cost_per_sqm + self.ink_per_sqm) * 0.0626514876),
      cost_a3: (self.cost_per_sqm + self.ink_per_sqm) * 0.124548139)
    )
  end

end

class MaterialCost < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :materials
end
```

`after_create` specifies a block of code to be run automatically on each Material after it has been created. `create_material_cost` is a helper method which is generated when you use has_one relationships. It allows you to create a MaterialCost which is automatically associated with the given Material.

As for your migrations, yes rails will automatically add an id column if you do not specify one. The default name is :id. What rails does **not** add automatically is a foreign key column to link your MaterialCosts to their parent Material. You can add this by creating a new migration:

```
class AddMaterialIDToMaterialCosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :material_costs, :material_id, :integer
  end
end
```

To reset your database and reload your migrations, run:

```
rails db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

Be warned that this will **delete all existing data** in your database.

Comment: thanks @eiko, looks great. Having trouble seeding to test it. Should be ok soon!

Comment: @godhar i edited my answer to include comments concerning your migration woes.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are on right track but you need to change few things a bit

1. `has_one` must be singular
2. `belongs_to` must be singular
3. You can make use of `after_create` callback to create associated `material_cost` for `Material`
4. You don't need `@material = current_material` as you can refer to it as `self`
5. If you are using `build` you need to save the instance or use `create`
6. Use `CONSTANT` for the values like `0.0626514876` and `0.124548139` so if you need to change them you don't need to search them project-wide.

So, after fixing these things the code will be

**material.rb**

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_entries
  has_one :material_cost, :material_charge, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :set_material_cost
  A3_FACTOR = 0.124548139
  A4_FACTOR = 0.0626514876

  private

  def set_material_cost
    @material_cost = self.create_material_cost(
      cost_a4: (cost_per_sqm + ink_per_sqm) * A4_FACTOR,
      cost_a3: (cost_per_sqm + ink_per_sqm) * A3_FACTOR
    )
  end
end
```

**material_cost.rb**

```
class MaterialCost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :material
end
```

Comment: thanks @Deepak...that looks like the right syntax, now I am having trouble seeding Material table to see if it does create a record for material_costs. I get: unknown attribute material_id for MaterialCost. I thought rails formatted all ids for relationships?

Comment: @godhar sorry for the slow response. have you generated any migrations for your db yet? if so, could you post your migration files for Material and MaterialCost?

Comment: yes I have a range of migrations. I had switched off my machine and the psql server, then when I started it up and re-create the tables and migrations. All these errors have occurred.

Comment: `class CreateMaterials < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :materials do |t|
      t.string :product_name, :guk_name
      t.integer :roll_width_in, :roll_length_m, :factor, :rounded_sale_price
      t.float :list_price, :cost_per_sqm, :ink_per_sqm, :supplier_discount, :sell_per_sqm
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end`

Comment: It works now, I did bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development in the terminal. I had to run delete a column name in one of the migration files as per error and then ran rake db:migrate.